# How to setup CodeIgniter with nginx allowing for SSL?

Tags: nginx, ssl, https, codeigniter

My `nginx.conf` file has:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    listen       443;
    server_name  www.mysite.com;

    #charset koi8-r;

    #access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;
    root /var/www/mysite/current;
    index index.html index.php;

    location ~* \.(ico|css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)(\?[0-9]+)?$ {
      expires max;
      log_not_found off;
    }

    location / {
      try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    }

    location ~* \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      include fastcgi.conf;
    }
}
```

This works, except won't do SSL on port 443. Any idea why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set `ssl_certificate` or `ssl_certificate_key`, which I believe are required to actually use SSL. You can use self-signed certificates if you don't have one from a CA.

Comment: How do I get self-signed ones?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=self+signed+certificate+nginx